# I accidentally ejaculated before I woke up!

Tags: nocturnal-emission

I woke up and I don’t know what happened but right before I did, I ejaculated and I have this feeling of extreme guilt. Is it okay that I did this but I asked for forgiveness right away. I still can’t shake this feeling of though. Please help

Comment: There's no reason of feeling guilty from Janabah or ihtilam (nocturnal emission) as it is something God given which requires ghusl and is actually mentioned in both qur'an and sunnah.

Answer (score 0):

Being ejaculated during sleeping is not a sin, because it has been done in your sleeping, not in your awaking/reality; hence, there is no need of being guilty ... although asking God for to forgive is great forever ... but canonically, it is wajib for you to do related Ghusl, just it!